# JSP: Iterate over List and get each item (ForEach)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having a hard time iterating over a List with jsp. I did this several times with velocity, but I somehow can't get it to work with jsp.

This is an easy example I am trying to get to work:

```
       @RequestMapping("/bye")
    public ModelAndView byeWorld() {
        String message = "Goodbye World, Spring 4.1.2!";

        List<Map<String, Object>> data = dataProvider.getVorgaengeGesamtByArkNr();

        model.put("table", data);
        model.put("columnNames", utils.getColumnNames(data));
        return new ModelAndView("test", model);
    }
```

`utils.getColoumnNames` returns an List.

This is the lopp in the .jsp:

```
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${columnNames}">
        <tr>
            entry
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Response looks like this:

```
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="[ARKNR_ABTEILUNG, LIEFERANT_ID, LIEFERANT_NAME, RECHNUNGS_NR, RECHNUNGS_DATUM, RECHNUNGS_EINGANG, STATUS_ID, STATUS_NAME_DE, RECHNUNGS_BETRAG_BRUTTO, RECHNUNGS_BETRAG_WAEHRUNG, SKONTO, WEITERBERECHNUNG, ARCHIV_ID, PROZESS_ID, AKTUELLER_BENUTZER, AKTUELLER_BENUTZER_ID, RECHNUNG_ID, KV_ID, ARKNR, DEPARTMENT_ID, FIBU_NAME, DBRD_ID]">
    <tr>
        entry
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

So the list is just replacing `${columnNames}`, not looping through it at all.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<String> getColumnNames(List list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        Map map = (Map)list.get(0);
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Object entry : map.keySet())
        {
            logger.debugT(entry.toString());
            columnNames.add(entry.toString());
        }

        return columnNames;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i added the code of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Example</h2>

    <c:if test="${not empty columnNames}">
         <h2>Columns</h2>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="col" items="${columnNames}">
                <li>${col}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This also fails. This results in the following server response:  <c:forEach var="entry" items="">
     <tr>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
 </c:forEach>

Comment: okay this works! Now i get a list displayed with all coloumNames

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `${}`, also use `td` to make it visible within table.

```
<tr>
   <td>${entry}</td>
</tr>
```

**Edited:**

As Jackk already pointed out, you need to import that taglib in order to use `forEach` on the top of the jsp.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I understand, but if this woudl've been the mistake, then it hsould have displayed 'entry' several times on the website, but there is just one time 'entry'

Comment: I added this, but still no change. Do I need any additional tags but yours? I saw <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> for example, but this makes it even worse.